# Derivatives non-negative function

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

> Let $f(x)\in C^{\infty}[a,b]$. For each $x\in [a,b]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f^{(n)}(x)\geqslant0$. Prove:
>   $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n,~\forall x\in[a,b]$$

The hint tells me to evaluate the remainder but I don't know how to do with it exactly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is proved in Tom Apostol's **Mathematical Analysis** as a standard theorem. See Theorem 9.30 (Bernstein) page 243.

Comment: Also note that the final conclusion holds with $\forall x\in[a, b) $ and not $\forall x\in[a, b] $.